# Spring Bean for sending email

Tags: java, spring

I need to create a bean with this structure:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getSender() {
   JavaMailSender jms = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

   // here I need somehow to set up to object sender's email, password, subject, port ...

   return jms;
}
```

When I get the bean from context, I need to have the object set up with all the properties except body content, which I will set. Is it possible to do this, and how if so?

Comment: Replace your comment by actual code doing what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `JavaMailSender` interface doesn't obligate the implementation to provide host, port and other SMTP information. However, one of its [implementing class](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html) `JavaMailSenderImpl` provides those methods.

All, you have to do is change the type of the variable `jms` to `JavaMailSenderImpl`, call the setters and then return it.

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);

    mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPassword("password");

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return (JavaMailSender)mailSender;
}
```